# I have troubles with axis_canvas from cowplot package on R: "Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2"

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I'm trying to add marginal boxplot next to a scatterplot that I've created with ggplot. To add the marginal boxplot I'm using the package cowplot (also because ggmarginal was always giving me boxplots of different width among them). Nevertheless it works for only x axis but not y axis.

#### That is my code for the scatterplot:

```
data_merged %>%  
  filter(treatment !="ctr") %>% 
  split(.$compartment)  %>% 
  map(
    ~ggplot(., 
            aes(x=time_after_treatment, y=max_peak, 
                fill=treatment, colour=treatment))+
      scale_colour_manual(values=c("#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#a6cee3")) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#a6cee3")) +
      geom_point(size=3) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits= c(2.5,17))+
      scale_y_continuous (limits= c(0.4, 2.0, 0.5)) +
      theme_classic() +
      labs(y= Ca^"2+"~peak~(mu*M), x= "Time (min)") +
      theme(#axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
            legend.position = "none",
            axis.text=element_text(size=11),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            strip.background = element_blank()) 
  ) -> list_scatter
```

#### That is the code I use to create the marginal x axis boxplot and it works fine

```
data_merged %>%  
  filter(treatment !="ctr") %>% 
  filter(compartment == "cytosol") -> data_cyt 

xbox_P3 <- axis_canvas(list_scatter[[1]], axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) +
  geom_boxplot(data=data_cyt, 
               aes(y=time_after_treatment, x=treatment, fill=treatment))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#a6cee3"))+
  scale_x_discrete() +coord_flip()

P3 <- insert_xaxis_grob(list_scatter[[1]], xbox_P3, 
                        grid::unit(0.9, "in"), position="top")
P3_plot <- ggdraw(P3)
```

#### That is the code I use to try to add the marginal y axis boxplot that it does not work

```
ybox_P4 <- axis_canvas(list_scatter[[2]], axis = "y") +
  geom_boxplot(data=data_cyt, 
               aes(y=max_peak, x=treatment, fill=treatment))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1f78b4", "#b2df8a", "#a6cee3"))+
  scale_x_discrete()
```

#### but it gives me this error message

> Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2
>
> 5. stop("x must be length 1 or 2")
> 6. zero_range(range)
> 7. scales::expand_range(range, expand[1], expand[2])
> 8. get_scale_limits(layer_scales(plot)$y)
> 9. axis_canvas(list_scatter[[2]], axis = "y")

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing scale_y_continuous withing the scatterplot function. It was needed to set the limits and the breaks separately in this way:

```r
scale_y_continuous (limits= c(0.4, 2.0), breaks=seq(0.4, 2.0, 0.5))
```